# The selection of the direction of the auxiliary curve when applying green's theorem to line integral with a singular point seems to change the answer

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

## Problem

Compute
$$
\oint_L\frac{xdy-ydx}{4x^2+y^2}
$$
where $L$ is a circle centered at $(1, 0)$ with a radius of $R > 1$, and the direction of $L$ is counterclock-wise.

## Solution

To by pass the singular point at $(0, 0)$ which is inside the circle $L$ surrounds, adding an auxiliary curve:
$$
C:4x^2+y^2 = \delta^2
$$
The integral can then be computed by applying Green's theorem. However, different choices of the direction of $C$ produce different answers. If we choose counterclock-wise:
$$
\oint_L\frac{xdy-ydx}{4x^2+y^2}=\oint_{L+C}-\oint_{C}=-\oint_{C}=-\pi
$$
， if we choose clockwise:
$$
\oint_L\frac{xdy-ydx}{4x^2+y^2}=\oint_{L+C^{-1}}-\oint_{C^{-1}}=\oint_{C}=\pi
$$

What I got wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The "pitfall" here is that Green's theorem only works with positively oriented boundaries/curves, which means that you need the correct orientation for $C$, which should be the opposite of that of $L$ (see for example this answer for the reasoning behind that: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141869/1104384), because you want and need the union of $L$ and $C$ to be positively oriented.

In this case, that means that $C$ must be oriented clockwise, hence you get $+ \pi$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. Image a walk along C, the counter-clockwise direction of C isn't the positively boundary of the shape created by L - C since my left arm is outside of the shape, the clockwise direction is.